# magento 1.9.0.1 products uploaded by CSV doesnt show

Tags: csv, import, product, magento-1.9

I am trying to upload products on magento 1.9.0.1 with CSV file. I added one product directly in magento then downloaded CSV file for adding more products on it.

When I import products they do show on magento backend but do not appear on store front end.

Please advise what I would be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> when import product using csv not active this product all product
>   status is disable. follow to step

1) First to refresh all cache.

2) Manage one by one product 
   select all product select    Change status Action and enable status.

3) then not display product please add one by one qty in product and see the product display status.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the products need to be "in stock". Instead of doing this per product in the backend, u need to have columns "qty" and "is_in_stock" in your import csv. In my experience, these columns are already there if u are using a template based on a product export csv.

I filled in for all products 
qty: 1
is_in_stock: 1

This resulted in my products showing in the store.